# Why I am getting module import error in git submodule when I run aws lambda locally?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have the following project directory.

```
|-app.py
|-module ( git submodule cloned during docker build)
    |-module1.py
```

My `app.py` is also simple.

```
import json
from module.module1 import MyClass


def lambda_handler(event, context):


    instance_class = MyClass()

    print("Everything should work")

    status = "ok"

    return json.dumps({"status": status})
```

Now my docker-compose file is given below:

```
FROM python:3.8-buster
RUN apt-get update
RUN python3.8 -m pip install awslambdaric
RUN git config --global submodule.recurse true
RUN git clone -b develop https://XXXXX.XXXX.XXXXX.git --recurse-submodules
COPY app.py ./
ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/local/bin/python3.8", "-m", "awslambdaric" ]
CMD ["app.lambda_handler"]
```

where the `https://XXXXX.XXXX.XXXXX.git` is my submodule link which I clone.

I execute the AWS lambda locally using the following command:

```
sudo sam build
```

This builds my docker file, then I run it as a local server using the following command.

```
sudo sam local start-api -p 8001
```

which start a local server

```
Mounting ModelTestFunction at http://127.0.0.1:8001/ [POST]
You can now browse to the above endpoints to invoke your functions. You do not need to restart/reload SAM CLI while working on your functions, changes will be reflected instantly/automatically. You only need to restart SAM CLI if you update your AWS SAM template
2022-02-15 15:32:19  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8001/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Now I send a post request to the API and I get the following error.

```
Building image.................
Skip pulling image and use local one: modeltestfunction:rapid-1.31.0.

START RequestId: f968ea74-1e26-453a-9b74-002554af09f8 Version: $LATEST
Traceback (most recent call last): Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'module.module1'
END RequestId: f968ea74-1e26-453a-9b74-002554af09f8
REPORT RequestId: f968ea74-1e26-453a-9b74-002554af09f8  Init Duration: 1.08 ms  Duration: 4489.90 ms    Billed Duration: 4500 ms    Memory Size: 10000 MB   Max Memory Used: 10000 MB   
Lambda returned empty body!
Invalid lambda response received: Invalid API Gateway Response Keys: {'requestId', 'errorMessage', 'stackTrace', 'errorType'} in {'errorMessage': "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'module.module1'", 'errorType': 'Runtime.ImportModuleError', 'requestId': 'f968ea74-1e26-453a-9b74-002554af09f8', 'stackTrace': []}
2022-02-15 15:33:34 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2022 15:33:34] "POST /model_test HTTP/1.1" 502 -
```

So It is clear that it is not able to load the git submodules. What to do here, how to fix this to run the lambda locally with the git submodule?